# Is EMF induced in a conducting loop moving in a uniform magnetic field with uniform velocity perpendicular to the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetic, induction

Due to the the magnetic force= q(v × B), the separation of charges must take place. One point must be at high potential than the other. So can't we just take the separation of the charges as the induced EMF?

Whereas Faraday's law defies this logic.

Comment: Where do you get a uniform field? Doesn’t it concentrate at the poles ?

Comment: From the earth‘s magnetic poles, I get a rather nice and uniform magnetic field here in Zürich ;-)

Comment: @Seresth Jain: Can you elaborate a little more what you are thinking? What is your setup and what do you expect?

Comment: It's Shresth @Stefan Wyss my setup is a simple one with a uniform magnetic field and a loop of wire moving with uniform velocity perpendicular to the field . I expect the charges to be separated due to magnetic force and hence formation of emf

Comment: Your expectation seems right to me.

Comment: Why does faraday's law defy this logic - explain please and justify.

Comment: According to Faraday law emf= -d(magnetic flux)/dt. And since magnetic flux is not changing so emf comes out to be zero.

Comment: Well, faraday's law is true so maybe you need to show a picture of your loop and the magnetic field so that your question is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faradays law is about changing flux in a coil. Your setup (with steady flux) and a moving coil is subject to the Lorentz force and is called Lorentz law.

Both laws do co-exist and they have little in common: Faraday is an electrodynamic law (derived from Maxwell equations), whereas Lorentz is an electrostatic law (derived from Einsteins special relativity).

Comment: so is an emf induced or not?

Comment: Yes, there is EMF induced in the coil.